# How to add a new instance of a rectangle into the view?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to add new multiple `rectangles` in different places on the `view`  in `runtime` dynamically. Later I'll use those rectangles to show some text on them when user clicks on them.

So, I thought the way to do it, by adding the pre-defined `rectangles` into an `observed array` and dynamically drawing each as follows.
However, as I need the rectangles to be drawn on different positions, I added an `offset`, but now that offset is popping errors.

1. Why the following errors occur,
2. How can I add rectangles on view in the places I want in `runtime`? Is there any better method than this (to draw in runtime)?

[image: The screenshot of the code with the error]

```
struct Columns: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var columnsArrayObservedObject = ViewModel() 
    
    @State private var offset: CGPoint
    
    var body: some View {
                          
        ZStack {
            ForEach(columnsArrayObservedObject.columnsArray, id: \.id) { column in
                
                Rectangle ()
                    .fill (Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .offset(offset)
            }
        }
       
        .frame(width:100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        
           }
}
```

Comment: try `.position(offset)`, and it is better to use `@StateObject var columnsArrayObservedObject ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try this approach, where each `TextRectangle` has its own (x,y) position.
Then a `ZStack` is used to overlay the `Rectangle` with the associated text at the desired position,
as shown in the example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Columns()
    }
}

struct TextRectangle: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var columnsArray: [TextRectangle] =     [
        TextRectangle(name: "1", x: Double.random(in: 0..<100), y: Double.random(in: 0..<100)),
        TextRectangle(name: "2", x: Double.random(in: 0..<100), y: Double.random(in: 0..<100)),
        TextRectangle(name: "3", x: Double.random(in: 0..<100), y: Double.random(in: 0..<100)),
        TextRectangle(name: "4", x: Double.random(in: 0..<100), y: Double.random(in: 0..<100))]
}
    


   struct Columns: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    let w = 200.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 50){
            Button("Add new") {
                vm.columnsArray.append(TextRectangle(name: "\(vm.columnsArray.count + 1)", x: Double.random(in: 0..<w), y: Double.random(in: 0..<w)))
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            ZStack {
                ForEach($vm.columnsArray) { $column in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill (Color.black)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                column.isSelected.toggle()
                            }
                        if column.isSelected {
                            Text(column.name).foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        }
                    }.position(x: column.x, y: column.y)
                }
            }.frame(width: w, height: w, alignment: .center)
                .padding(30)
                .border(.red)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the error you get with `.offset(offset)` is because you declare `offset` a `CGPoint`, but the modifier `.offset(offset)` takes a `CGSize` as parameter, or `.offset(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)`